# How to pass the thread culture from the application to the sql server without creating an additional parameter in every procedure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, localization, internationalization

I have an ASP.NET application that uses XML as Resource to support a range of languages and locales.

The Web.config is configured with the following node:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization enableclientbasedculture="true" uiculture="auto" culture="auto">                </globalization>
</system.web>
```

And It works very well. The ASP.NET thread on the server is automatically configured to run on the client culture, which is great for locating strings.

Now I need to create some localized strings and store it on the Sql Server. However, I store the string with some keys for further formatting and, for performance purposes, I would like to reduce round-trips to the database by processing related strings in stored procedures during some selects.

> What are the best practices to pass the user language from the
>   application to the sql server and get the user language in a stored
>   procedure or function to switch to the desired tuple (language-resourceKey-resourceValue) in the table that contains the localized strings?

Things I would like to avoid:

- Passing the thread culture as parameter of every stored procedure that needs to return some localized (and processed) strings.

Things I would like to achieve:

- Keep the code DRY (solve the problem in a centralized part of the system)
- A scalable and generic solution (something easy to maintain)

---

I considered the possibility of wrapping the command execution at application level to include the parameter when applicable, but i still need to include the parameter in every procedure and I am trying to get this information in a more transparent manner.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best solution would be to pass it as a parameter every time.

To accomplish this you can create a wrapper function for all your calls to the database.
This function would automatically add the User Language parameter and pass it to every stored procedure. This means that every procedure will need that parameter defined.

The benefits of this solution is:
1. You never have to worry about passing the parameter.
2. Even if you don't need to localize something you still have the option to if the need for it comes in the future. With no need of changing the application.

Sending a single parameter every time will not have a performance hit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I considered this possibility. I will w8 to see if someone else has something different to propose.

Comment: after 2 days with no other answer, I think this solution is the common approach. Thanks ;)